# Obtaining a value from a different column if one column contains a specific character in text

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a new measure that retrieves a value based on a text value in power bi. In my case that character is "2" and that will retrieve a value from the KW column. Apologies for the screenshot

[image]

I tried the CONTAINS function, however that only gives me a yes or no value. How do I return a value from the KW column based on the Month column with the character "2"

```
KW2 = CONTAINS('Sähko usage 2023',Month,2)
```